# Can a transformer output current be controlled by a current limiting switch on the input?

Tags: transformer, ac, current-limiting, step-down

I have a step down transformer, input of 220/40v, however I need to vary the current on the output.

I understand that by varying the voltage (using a device such as a Variac) on the input I could change the voltage on the output which would change the current drawn, but I'm wondering if there is another way to go about this?

TLDR: is it possible to use a **current limiting device**, like a light dimmer switch, **on the input to control the max current on the output?**

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you need consistent voltage? Or current?

Comment: Neither need to be completely consistent, but the max current needs to be varied. Could this be done by using something which 'crops' AC voltage? Like a dimmer switch

Comment: Please describe what you are trying to do. There are too many unknowns to answer. For example, I still don't know if you need current limiting or if you just want to reduce the voltage to decrease the current. It is not quite the same thing. It is also not clear whether you need the voltage to be sinusoidal or not because a dimmer will not do this.

Comment: A light dimmer is not a current limiting device at all, it chops up the voltage in a particular way to result in less RMS voltage at the load. Please explain the nature of your load and exactly what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Smells XY to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

max current can be varied by putting variable resistance in series.

this could be a carbon pile rheostat,a  variable inductor, magnetic amplifier, or even  home-made deathdrap like a scariac. a reverse wired variac driving a resistive load.

Another approach would be to use a motor-generator and to vary the generators field current to vary the output current.

Answer (score 0):

The VA rating of your transformer determines the maximum current that may be safely drawn from it.

The output current would be determined only by the load connected to the secondary.

A variac or autotransformer on the primary side would change the output VA (both voltage and current).

A light dimmer would chop the waveform and also make it asymmetrical, resulting in noise and interference.